# Using 220V wiring for a 12V setup

Tags: wiring, 12v

I am living in a static house that uses a 220V system for lighting fridge etc, I wish to set my solar system up using 12V not 220, I have a gas fridge and don't need 220V, I will only have 7 LED lights (5W each) and a phone charging here and there; nothing over 12V, except my laptop that needs 17V. I believe I can use a universal charger that has an adapter that can do this, or could I use a 150W inverter with a cigarette lighter plug, can the existing wiring take the heat?
My point is I don't want 220.

My question is can I use the existing wiring that is 220V and just change the fuses in the existing box, or should I make a new fusebox? Whole new wiring or save my time and money and just change the light fixings and plug sockets?
I really appreciate your advice as I am on a budget and can't afford to do things wrong.

Comment: if you imagine the same power , then you need 10x the Ampacity which is about 3 gauges for double so the wire gauge for 8x ampacity then the wire gauge must be 27 gauges larger than typical AWG16.  this means if you do not do this, your resistance losses will be too much.  Start with specs for power and loads then determine acceptable losses.

Comment: e.g. if a long wire drops 10% of 120Vac at 15A , it will drop 12Vac thus using  12Vdc 10% drop will dim LEDstrips 40% using only 1A or 1.2V as almost 100% dim is only a 2.8V drop 9.2V.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the house is **completely** disconnected from the power grid, with **absolutely no way for external 220 VAC to reach the house**, i.e. it is completely isolated and, perhaps, any power entrance cable has been removed, to prevent accidental connection, then this could work.

There is one big limitation: no more current can go through the existing house wiring than can at present, with the existing circuit breakers (or fuses). This means a loss of power by a factor of ~18. For example, if you had 15 ampere circuits, the maximum power draw from each would be 15 A * 220 VAC, 3,300 W. Using 12 VDC, you could draw 15 A * 12 VDC, 180 W. That would be barely enough for 5 LED lamps at 7 W (35 W) and the 150 W converter. Each additional circuit could handle the same current.

**N.B.:** You must also comply with any local codes, which may prohibit that use of the house wiring!

Comment: Given the concern with local codes, I'd check to see if anyone else in your country has done the same thing.  You never know what weirdness lurks in the electrical code that makes sense with how things were done 30 years ago.

Comment: If I kept the existing breaker box I would put a **GIANT** placard on it explaining that the house is on 12V and to never, ever, connect 220V to the box.

Comment: @TimWescott Some code oddities: (1) NEC code is good. But it permits 20' of #4 bare copper embedded in a concrete foundation as a "Ufer ground." This is so, even if (as is usually the case) lots of rebar (and anchor bolts) is in the concrete. Putting two such dissimilar metals in a wet sponge (concrete) isn't wise. I believe only the 20' rebar option is the way to go for a Ufer in the presence of other rebar. (2) An old architecture textbook I have states that the front door of a home must be hogged out of a tree trunk as a single piece. That idea died in the 1940's (for obvious reasons.)

Comment: Isn't 10A*12V=120W?

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik thank you for your reply, the breaker box has 3 breakers, mains coming in will be connected straight from the 12V battery, it has 40A breaker, sockets have 20A breakers and the lights have a 6A breaker. do I need to increase the Lighting breaker? I will be removing the plug from the exterior so no mains power can come into the static house.

Comment: @sweber, THANKS! I must have been half-asleep doing that math. Example has been redone.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely won't work because the cables are too long. If you put 12V at the input of some 1.5mm² cross section wire as typical for 230V wiring and draw a few amperes, the load will see less than 10V. The remainder is turned into heat in the wiring.

This is less important with 230V as the current for the same power is only 1/18, and 2V drop of 220V is less than 1% while at 12V, it's nearly 20%.

---

Go check how thick the wiring in your car is. And that's at most 5 metres long.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought as I am only powering LED the drop won't be that noticable, the cables are maybe 9M long max, Still don't think it will work?

Comment: A 3W LED draws 250mA at 12V. Take ten and you are at 2.5A already.

Comment: @Janka, if the circuit is 20 A, it's probably 12 gauge (USA). The voltage drop for **15 A is ~1.5 V** for a 10 m run. Your calculation is a bit pessimistic. See https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html

Comment: My calculation was with 50m of wire (25m forth and 25m back) and 230V wiring, which is only 1.5mm² usually.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. if a long wire drops 10% of 120Vac at 15A , it will drop 12Vac thus using  12Vdc 10% drop will dim LEDstrips 40% using only 1A or 1.2V as almost 100% dim is only a 2.8V drop 9.2V.

NO GOOD.